Woman is chased into a morgue with floating bodies
This is a film I've seen as a child, and it obviously has haunted me for quite a while. I still haven't found out its name, so I wonder if someone here might be able to help. Here's a rough outline: 

A woman is being chased by a menacing guy. First, she hides under a
  steel table, I think she might have grabbed a scalpel for defense. 
Then she runs off into the next room, which is very eerie. It is a
  very large room with a lot of coffin-like stone (or steel) tanks which
  are filled with water. In the water, strange looking corpses are
  floating. 
The woman hides in one of the tanks under a corpse.

That's pretty much all I can remember. I've seen it in the late 80s, perhaps very early 90s. Let me know if you recognize it!

So how old is this film? Is it in English?

I've seen in the late 80s or early 90s. I have no idea if it's English. I have most likely seen it in German, but there's about a 70% chance it was dubbed from another language.

Ah, and when reading about "floating bodies", I immediately thought about Coma, but those were unconcious people hanging on wires, I think.

I thought of Coma too, @NapoleonWilson

It is Mortal Fear from 1994 based on a novel by Robin Cook:

Elderly and middle-aged patients in a big-city hospital are mysteriously dying, soon after having routine check-ups. When one of her friends becomes the latest victim, a doctor becomes suspicious of everyone around her, including research doctors and her new lover.

If I remember correctly, the heroine hides from the bad guy in a tank of formalin under a body.
